# Inferring Nullity runs forever

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

When I select *Analyze - Infer nullity...* in the android studio menu and select any scope (tried even running on a single file) message pops up and says:

> The module ... doesn't refer to the existing 'support-annotations'
>   library with Android nullity annotations. Would you like to add
>   dependency now?

I click "OK" and then gradle sync starts and progress bar with "infer nullity annotations" title is shown. Then it **runs forever** like this

I tried adding manually this in gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
```

But still have the same result.

Comment: Run into same issue, don't know what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, but I managed to solve it by manually adding the newest version of the annotations support library to the project through Android Studio build options (it's found on Build -> Edit Libraries and Dependencies on Mac).

The thing here is that Android Studio will probably give you some kind of a warning if you add a support library whose version number is higher than your target API build, but add it anyway. Not sure why, but that did the trick for me.